How to solve "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ"?
I am struggling in my R class and need help with fixing the part that is in bold towards the end of my script below. The error I keep getting after running the bolded code is: Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ. To add some context, I am trying to create a linear regression model based on my dataset and then generate a polynomial regression line over my linear regression graph. Thanks in advance for the help!!! Here is my script:
library(rstudioapi)[text] 
options(scipen = 999) 
options(digits = 3)
rm(list=ls())
load("carData.rdata")
set.seed(25)
trainIndex <- sample(1:nrow(carData), trunc(nrow(carData) * 0.75))
train <- carData[trainIndex,]
test <- carData[-trainIndex,]
lm.results <- lm(Price~., data=train)
library(car)
numeric_columns <- sapply(carData, is.numeric)
numeric_data <- carData[, numeric_columns]
correlation_matrix <- cor(numeric_data)
vif_values <- vif(lm(Price ~ ., data = numeric_data))
print(correlation_matrix)
print(vif_values) 
summary(lm.results)
train$Model <- factor(train$Model)
test$Model <- factor(test$Model)
test$Model <- factor(test$Model, levels = levels(train$Model))
predprice <- predict(lm.results, newdata = test)
rmse <- sqrt(mean((test$Price-predprice)^2, na.rm=TRUE))
print(round(rmse,2))
poly_results <- lm(Price ~ poly(predict(lm.results), 2), data = train)
poly_predprice <- predict(poly_results)
par(mar = c(3, 3, 1, 1))

#problematic line:
plot(train$Price, 
     predprice, 
     xlab = "Observed Price", ylab = "Predicted Price", 
     main = "Linear Regression: Observed vs. Predicted Prices", 
     cex.axis = 0.8)

lines(sort(train$Price), sort(poly_predprice), col = "blue")  

Below is a pic of the error I am getting:


Hello didi and welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is not a bad first attempt at a question, you have provided the code in a copy-pastable format and identified the exact error message and where it occurs.  The question could be improved by making a minimal reproducible example, but I think there is enough here for people to make a start.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

The error occurs because in plot(train$Price, predprice, ...) the first two arguments are different lengths, so don't make an exact tidy set of x/y coordinate pairs.  What do you get it you run length(train$Price) and length(predprice)?

You have split your dataset into train and test, so you are now dealing with two different sets (with different number of records). To make plot() happy, x- and y-series lengths must be equal. For example, attempting to plot with vectors of lengths 3 & 2 ( plot(c(1,2,3), c(1,2)) ) reproduces the error you are seeing.
And to have a meaningful scatterplot of observations and predictions, those should also originate from the same set (i.e. training)
Following example uses mtcars dataset for reproducibility:
# mtcars dataset, check `?mtcars` for more details
head(mtcars)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

str(mtcars)
#> 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  11 variables:
#>  $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>  $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>  $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>  $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>  $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>  $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>  $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>  $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>  $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...

set.seed(25)

# split dataset into train and test
trainIndex <- sample(1:nrow(mtcars), trunc(nrow(mtcars) * 0.75))
train <- mtcars[trainIndex,]
test <- mtcars[-trainIndex,]

# unmber records in train and test sets:
nrow(train)
#> [1] 24
nrow(test)
#> [1] 8

lm.results <- lm(mpg~., data=train)

# number of results when predicting on training set
length(predict(lm.results))
#> [1] 24
# number of results when predicting on test set
length(predict(lm.results, newdata = test))
#> [1] 8

# plot predictions vs observations
plot(predict(lm.results) ~ train$mpg)



